# Translating "Slow down!" (in informal contexts)

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, formalidad, modismos

## English

[WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=slow%20down) translates "slow down" as *disminuir la velocidad* or *desacelerar*. But those sound pretty precise or technical to me. How would you translate "Slow down!" in other, more informal contexts like:

- You are driving with a friend who is speeding and driving recklessly and you want him to stop.
- A friend is excitedly describing something to you and is talking too fast to understand.

Surely you don't say *¡Disminuye la velocidad!*, do you?

---

## Español

[WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=slow%20down) traduce "slow down" como "disminuir la velocidad" o "desacelerar". Pero me suenan bastante precisos o técnicos. Cómo traduciríais "Slow down!" en otros contextos más informales como:

- Vas en el coche/auto/carro con un amigo que va a excesiva velocidad y conduciendo imprudentemente y quieres que lo deje.
- Un amigo está animado/exitado describiéndote algo y está hablando demasiado rápido para entenderle.

Seguro que no decís *¡Disminuye la velocidad!*, ¿o sí?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Surely not, or yes... ;) You can say that informally, but if you don't want to offend your friend :P

When driving:

- ¡Frena! (Although it means "brake", it does not mean to completely stop, but slow down)
- ¡No vayas tan rápido/deprisa! (This is really used instead of saying "slow down". Not going so fast means that the driver has to slow down).
- ¡Más despacio!

Telling a friend to chill out:

- ¡Más despacio!
- ¡No vayas tan rápido/deprisa!
- ¡Frena! (As Laura says. Actually, you can use any of the ones for driving).
- ¡Pisa el freno, Madaleno! (In Spain)

These are the ones I can think of now.

Comment: Frena! can also be used in the second example (lo de .. magdaleno me ha encantado :D)

Comment: To "chill out," I often hear simply "tranquilo!"

Comment: @Flimzy That one’s often just *¡Tranqui, tranqui!* for cool it, calm down, take it easy, settle down, don’t worry be happy, like don’t have a cow man.  It’s actually short for *tranquilízate* (< *tranquilizarse*), which is too darn long to say.  This *might* be more of an Madrileñan thing, or a Northern Spanish thing, or a Spain-Spanish thing, or even an Iberian thing, than one heard throughout Greater Hispanophonia; maybe so maybe not, but I don’t have enough datapoints to say. Certainly it’s itself perfectly normal in the streets of Madrid, and I think probably also of Barcelona and Sevilla.

Comment: I would like to give you more points just for the Madaleno reference (although I always heard it like "¡Echa el freno, Madaleno!". When I write it, I hear my father's voice.

Answer (score 2):

When telling a friend to slow down:

> ¡Baja las revoluciones!
>
> ¡Cálmate un poco!

When driving:

> ¡Anda/Conduce más lento!

Answer (score 1):

As JoulSauron already pointed out, "frena" is quite common. It could mean "slow down" as well as "stop". So it might be a bit ambiguous without context. "Frena un poco" could be used too. Note that by adding "un poco", "frena" could only mean "slow down" in this case.

"Bajá/baja un poco (la velocidad)" is also common informally (at least here in Argentina). "La velocidad" is implied but often not said. In the same vein, "aflojá/afloja un poco (con el acelerador)" has the same general meaning but is a bit more informal.

Another option that comes to mind (again this might be a local thing) is "bajá/baja un cambio" (drop down a gear, if that makes sense; I'm not sure if this is a good translation). Although, thinking about it, I've always heard (and used) this expression figuratively, rather than in its literal sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I were Argentinian, I'd say "*Che, ¡relájate!*" in both situations.

If Spaniard, "*No tan deprisa, ¡porfa!*" in the car, and "*¡Porfi!, háblame menos rápido.*" when chatting.
`(Porfi/Porfa = Por favor)`

All the interjections add diplomacy and friendship to the phrase.
The better if joined by a hand gesture indicating *slow down*.

But, as I am a Brazilian, I just say *Tranki, my friend*, in Spanglish, followed by a :)

**[update]**
As *tchrist* points out, "tranqui" is quite extended in Spain. I lived in Andaluzia, Valencia and Asturias and used it. Also in Brasil and Venezuela.
And certainly, I'm still to find **any** person from a latin language background (br, pt, es, fr, it, cat) that doesn't understands it. Even if they didn't use the word, it has very powerful memetizing properties.
Recommended!

> but don't do it with your fiance`s father

Comment: Per [my comment above](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/translating-slow-down-in-informal-contexts/2253#comment3571_2253), it makes perfect sense to say *tranqui* in Spain, too.

Comment: @tchrist, duly noted, compai

Answer (score 0):

*Very* informal, but frequently used in Spain, in both contexts:
"¡Tranqui, tronco!" (where *tronco* means 'buddy')