# ¿Cuál es la manera más eficaz de decir 'slow down!' en español a alguien que conduce un patinete o una bici?

Tags: traducción

Si estás en una situación en la ciudad, en la calle, cuando miras a alguien yendo muy rápido en su patinete o bici, ¿cuál es la manera más eficaz, informal (aunque educada) y rápida para decir "slow down!"?

He visto [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/translating-slow-down-in-informal-contexts) a *casi* la misma pregunta, pero esa trata más de estar dentro de un coche. Para mí, "más despacio" me parece la respuesta más adecuada, pero quería ver si hubiera otra(s).

Comment: to be polite, and avoid problems, just add "por favor" at the beginning :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, "más despacio" es lo adecuado generalmente antecedido por el verbo - IR como:

- Ve más despacio
- Vayan más despacio
- ¡Más despacio niños!

Answer (score 3):

¡Hola! Hispanohablante aquí.

En casi todos los lugares hispanohablantes del mundo hay jergas y formas distintas de hablar.
Yo soy de Argentina, acá por ejemplo decimos: "Che rey, bajale la velocidad papito. Te podés lastimar." *sonrisa al final*.

Pero siempre que digas algo así será tomado como algo bueno y educado. (El tono de voz en el español cuenta muchísimo).

Posibles traducciones para **Slow down**:

- ¡Mas despacito!
- ¡Cuidado con la velocidad!
- ¡Bajale un cacho! (Argentinian idiom)

Comment: ¿Se puede decir ¡Aflojále un cacho!?

Comment: @cocteau De hecho ¡Sí!

Answer (score 3):

Generalmente, la persona puesta en peligro dirá, simplemente, "¡Cuidado!" Es lo más rápido y se entiende la intención, aunque no se haga referencia explícita a la velocidad.

Otra opción que me soprende que no aparezca, porque se usa mucho al menos en el sur de España es "No corras". Incluso si la persona no está literalmente corriendo, sino conduciendo una bici o un coche, el habla informal permite usar el "no corras".

[image: "no corras papá" cartel con fotos de niños, para que el padre recuerde a su familia antes de ponerse en riesgo en la carretera]

Y si no te preocupa una pequeña vulgaridad:

> [image: despacio coño]